# Add prefix to Row() function in Google sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I want to add a prefix to the Row() function in my formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(R1:R<>"",row(T1:T),""))
```

Seems like it should be simple, I am trying

```
=ArrayFormula(if(R1:R<>"",'prfix'&row(T1:T),""))
```

But I get "formula parse error"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just your format. Try this one:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(R1:R<>"";"prfix"&row(T1:T);""))
```

Comment: Thank Adam.  Say is there a general rule here? change `,` to `;` for concatenating? or  more generally how does one know when to change `,` to `;`

Comment: Can't tell for sure. Outside of queries I always use `;` instead of `,` , but I use german settings...